# How to keep iOS SpriteKit GameScene (physics, etc) running in the background (at least for one minute)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center, multiplayer

For iOS multiplayer game using GameCenter API, one of the device would be used as server and all the other player devices as 'client'. However, when anyone switch the game to background, all the physics, action, animations stops for that device. This is super fragile particularly for the 'server' player since he can cheat (e.g. quickly switch to background to avoid dying in the next second).

So how can I prevent the game from pausing immediately when switching to background? I know iOS has a limit on how long the app  can run but even if an extra minute would be enough for the app to detect this event and switch a server and transmit all necessary data before that.

However, now matter what I tried (e.g. add the background process capability for this app). Once I switch the app to background, I noticed all the physics in the SKScene pause immediately, there is no delay that I can process this state.

Any idea?

Comment: have you tried working with [background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks)? you will need to enable Capabilities / Background Modes via xcode target. then handle events accordingly.

Comment: @Fault I saw that, but it's not straightforward how I can directly put a SKScene and all physics simulation packed in a background task in those API. It's easier for some specific math function etc.